# Ubuntu 14 low screen resolution on intel HD display

Tags: 14.04, resolution, intel-graphics

I have a desktop (Intel HD 2500 card and Dell 1366*768 display) on which Ubuntu 14 LTS has been installed. But it is running on very low resolution of 1024*768. I tried intel graphics gui and updated the drivers; but the resolution is still low.

I have the same problem on Fedora 21, Ubuntu 14.10 and even on Windows 7 for a fresh install. On windows the problem was fixed when I installed intel drivers.

When I tried to edit xorg, higher display was available but the letters on screen, web, libre are fuzzy and difficult to read. I guess the xorg editing was just simulating a higher resolution.

Any suggestion on this would be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing the graphics drivers from intel ? They should work on your HD2500 GPU.

To install: open your terminal and perform these commands

Install the certificates:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
```

Install the intel-linux-graphics-installer (note that this is an example for the 64 bit driver. If you need another architecture please refer to the documentation link at the bottom of this post)

```
wget https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb
```

Update your system

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Install the drivers through the installation tool:

```
sudo intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

Reboot

See also the documentation: 
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions...

But, it does not work for me... The GUI was installed and all the graphics driver updates went fine too. But still the resolution is low. I don't see an option for the full resolution on settings:display...

Comment: You should take a look here then: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution